# FadeIn the Localstorage Value

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have few tabs which their ID is the Item in localstorage which I'm trying to fadeIn.

Tab fadeIn with: `$('Tab1').show();`
Now, I've set the value of '**Tabvalue**' to '**Tab1**' and I tried to fade it in as follow: `$("#" + $(localStorage.getItem("TabValue"))).Show();` but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try lowercasing the S in the second .Show(). Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#" + localStorage.getItem("TabValue")).show();
```

the localStorage value doesn't need to be wrapped in `$()` as it's a string, gets converted to an jQuery object, and back to a (mostly useless) string. Also, `Show()` needs to be `show()`.